# Conditional probability knowing probability of sick diagnosis and being sick and get sick diagnosis

Tags: conditional-probability

Conditional probability knowing probability of sick diagnosis and being sick and get sick diagnosis

I know that probability of sick diagnosis is 0.10 and i know that probability to be sick and get sick diagnosis is 0.08.

I know that the probability to be sick and get sick diagnosis is 0.08/0.10=0.80

How can i get probability when i am healthy and stil get sick diagnosis?

I know that $$P(\overline A|B)= 1- P(A|B) = 1- 0.8 = 0.2$$ but how can i use this to solve the problem? Is it just 0.10/0.20=0.5?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking.  When you say, "probability when i am healthy and still get sick diagnosis" do you mean the probability that you are healthy, given that you are diagnosed as sick, or do you mean the probability that you are diagnosed as sick, given that you are healthy?

Comment: If i understand correct i think i mean that i get sick diagnosis even i am healthy and not sick. I think from those two the first option.